# How to get event to my server when (user -> Update, Delete) from Keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

I use keycloak server for Authorization. I create my user in my database and in keycloak.
Now I need to delete user from my database when user is deleted in keycloak.
My server is written by Java.
How can I get event from keycloak to my server when user is deleted or updated in keycloak?

Comment: That sounds like a task for SCIM protocol, which is not implemented in the Keycloak atm - see/watch/vote https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-2537

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this example [KecyloakEventExample](https://medium.com/@adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-5bf9de1b0965)
I hope it will be useful

Answer (score 2):

I think you are better off using [Keycloak User Storage SPI feature](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi):

> **You can use the User Storage SPI to write extensions to Keycloak to
> connect to external user databases and credential stores.** The built-in
> LDAP and ActiveDirectory support is an implementation of this SPI in
> action. Out of the box, Keycloak uses its local database to create,
> update, and look up users and validate credentials. **Often though,
> organizations have existing external proprietary user databases that
> they cannot migrate to Keycloak’s data model.** For those situations,
> **application developers can write implementations of the User Storage
> SPI to bridge the external user store and the internal user object
> model that Keycloak uses to log in users and manage them.**

In this way you do not need to have some callback mechanism that is trigger whenever a user gets deleted, updated or whatever. You just configure your DB as an external user DB to be used by Keycloak. Moreover, you can configured it so that  whenever a user gets add, deleted, or update it reflect immediately on your DB. This approach is easier to implement, cleaner, more maintainable and performance- and memory- wise better.

Comment: I agree with @dreamcrash. There is not api that will push you some event out of keycloak, as long as I see the official apis https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api